# How can I refresh a TClientDataSet without applying pending updates?

Tags: database, delphi, dbexpress, tclientdataset

Here is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. Retrieve 1 record from the database through TSQLDataset's CommandText: SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = 1
2. Use TClientDataset to modify the record. (1 pending update)
3. Retrieve next record. SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE ID = 2
4. Modify the record. (now 2 pending updates)
5. Finally, send the 2 pending updates back to the database through ApplyUpdates function.

When I do step 3 I got "Must apply updates before refreshing data."

How can I refresh a TClientDataSet without applying pending updates?

Comment: The `TClientDataSet` is designed to hold many records.  The way you are using it to pull and modify one record at a time seems inefficient.  Wouldn't it be better to pull both (all) the records that the user needs to modify, let the user modify those records, then apply the updates to the database with `ApplyUpdates` all-at-once?

Comment: @James, what about a pontentially multi-million base table/record set, bringing all this data to the client to modify a couple of records seems much more inefficient.

Comment: @jachguate - I agree.  However, the most efficient approach seems to be to apply the updates before pulling more data.  But the OP didn't explain much about the table or why delayed (batched) updates is important.  If delayed updates are necessary, then your answer seems like the best solution.

Comment: @JamesL., I'm sorry, I should have stated the reason why I'm pulling one record at a time. The database contains 500K of records and pulling all these takes a lot of time and network resources. BTW, I'm not using any database grid just TDBEdits to modify each record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can append data packets manually to your DataSet calling the [AppendData](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/en/Datasnap.DBClient.TCustomClientDataSet.AppendData) method.

In an application where the provider is in the same application with the ClientDataSet you can code something like this:

```
begin
  ConfigureProviderToGetRecordWithID(1);
  //make the ClientDataSet fetch this single record and not hit the EOF.
  ClientDataSet1.PacketRecords := 1; 
  ClientDataSet1.Open;
  ClientDataSet1.Edit;
  ModifyFirstRecord;
  ClientDataSet1.Post;
  ConfigureProviderToGetRecordWithID(2);
  ClientDataSet1.AppendData(DataSetProvider1.Data, False); 
  //now you have two records in your DataSet without losing the delta.
end;
```

This is kind of pseudo-code, but shows the general technique you could use.